# parse cloud; How to write a query to get all data in a particular column

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I am apologize for this type Question. I am first time use Cloud Code in parse so I have No idea how to get data in parse through Cloud code. If any idea then suggest me. I have check many example but I have not found in my problem.
My parse data base is like this..

```
   userId    game1score    game2score  game3score   gender 
   xcvgfs1      300           200           100       man
   sfdgdh       500           600           300       man
```

like this parse data base many user are playing game and score the game.
My problem is how to get all user score in game1score ya other game score and compare to current user score and find the **Rank** of current user.
Thanks for helping..

Call the cloud code function is like this in my activity..

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(" game1score", "300");

        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("check_duplicate",map,new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void done(Object o, ParseException e) {
                if(e==null){
                   Log.e("String",""+o) ;
                }else{
                    Log.e("error",e.getMessage()) ;
                }
            }
        });
```

return always null or 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from your explanation, you want to extract the rank number of current user via using the Parse Score table where you record 3 different game scores (gameScore1, gameScore2, gameScore3).  You have already write the Cloud code trigger function. So the cloud code that you can use is below;

```
Parse.Cloud.define("rank", function(request, status) 
{
  var result = [];
  var processRankCallback = function(res) {
    result = result.concat(res);
    if (res.length === 1000) 
    {
      process(res[res.length-1].id);
      return;
    }
    //All object that is greater than the given user score
    status.success(result.length);
  }
  var processRank = function(skip) 
  {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Score");
    var userScore = request.params.userScore;
    var gameType = request.params.gameType;
    if (skip) query.greaterThan("objectId", skip);
    query.limit(1000);
    query.ascending("objectId");
    query.find().then(function querySuccess(res) 
    {
        var innerResult = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < res.length;i++)
        {
            //var gameScore1 = res[i].get("gameScore1");
            //var gameScore2 = res[i].get("gameScore2");
            //var gameScore3 = res[i].get("gameScore3");
            //var total = gameScore1+gameScore2+gameScore3;
            var total = res[i].get(gameType);
            if(userScore < total)  innerResult.push(res[i]);
        }
        processRankCallback(innerResult);
    }, function queryFailed(reason) 
    {
      status.error("Error:" + error.code + "  Message" + error.message);
    });
  }
  processRank(false);
});
```

Actually, finding the rank means that query the Score table and count the entry where the game scores all total is larger than your current user total game score. To implement this you can use the countQuery however Parse countQuery can fail or show incorrect result when your table entry is larger than 1000. So, instead of using count query, you can walk through the entire table and find all entries that have larger game score than your current user. In above code, I assume that you have 3 different game scores and all have valid number (not undefined). You can modify the code for your own purposes. The end result will generate a number which is actually the number of entry in Score table that has larger game score total than your current user game scores total.

For example I have a Score table with column gameScore1 and 3 entries where the scores are  600, 200 and 100. I call the Cloud function with below parameters hash table;

```
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("userScore", "150");
    params.put("gameType", "gameScore1");
    //Call Parse cloud function
```

The response will be 2 which actually means that  there are two entries that has gameScore1 which is larger than 150. Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: If I want to each different game rang.. means when i click button 1 then give game1 rank and when click the button 2nd then give the game2 Rank..

Comment: Dear Destro; I update the question and add some explanation part where you can give the gameScore as gameType (another input) and use it in innerResult calculation. Then for each button press you will give two inputs where the first one is your current user game score and the second is game type (gameScore1 or other). But be sure that your given gameType input will exist in Parse table.

Comment: Dear Destro; I have already created  your table structure on Parse and test it. It works. If you have further questions do not hesitate to ask. Regards.

Comment: it always return 0.. and i want particular game Rank... each game have different rank.

Comment: Dear Destro; I update the question again. I have already tried the answer in this post,  it definitely works. If result is 0 then it means that your are the first ( no entry found that has larger value that you specify as input). Regards.

Comment: if i want to print console.log("Game name: "+ innerResult);  how to show this result..

Comment: Dear Destro; The innerResult is an array. So you have to walk through it and for each object you have to get its game name innerResult[i].get("gameName"); Still not working?

Comment: if I want to check that my value are correct are not.. menace i want to any value are print in console.log("something","something");how to show this log and where.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Did you try the last edited code?