# Parse Cloud code : How to update table in parse cloud code

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform, cloud, parse-cloud-code

I want to update parse database table. That means i have 2 table in parse, 1 table is update through my app and 2nd table is update according to 1st table data. for example.

```
      userId    gamename    gamescore  gameani   
        1         G1        200        100      
        1         G1        600        300     
        2         G2        400        200   
        3         G3        500        430
```

And i want to 2nd table is this type

```
userId    G1topscore    G2topscore  G3topscore G1ani G2ani G3ani
   1        600               0          0      200    0      0
   2         0              400          0       0     200    0
   3         0              500          0       0     0     430
```

That means in the second table is update according to first table . In the first table has 1 user are created many row but in the update in second table has are shorting according to the user. score are shorting in the highest score and ANI is calculated in game average. How to update second table in cloud code.

Comment: Destro, have you previously set up cloud code/job in nparse?

Comment: I have no idea in parse cloud code because i have coding in parse cloud code in first time .. but see this example .. [Link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817954/parse-cloud-how-to-write-a-query-to-get-all-data-in-a-particular-calum

Comment: use background jobs here is link http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-background-jobs/